# What is happening with these diodes and transistors?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, diodes

http://www.generalguitargadgets.com/pdf/ggg_mxr_hpamp_sc.pdf

[image]

I'm sorry I don't have a proper way to ask this question because I don't even know what to call this configuration.

I modeled the circuit in LTspice. The signal is more amplified directly from pin 6 of the op-amp, but after this section, the signal strength drops by about 1.1 dB.

What is the point of this? I ran a simulation with this section included, and one without this section included, and the output was identical.

Comment: https://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Amplifiers/amplifiers55.php  see "Class AB Complementary Push Pull Output Stage"

Comment: It's a crude pre-biasing circuit to improve [crossover distortion](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/amp26.gif).

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What is happening is that these components are arranged so that they provide amplification for headphones.  Perhaps you might want to start with a simpler example.  For most people an emitter-follower is a good place to start learning about transistors.

Comment: @pat Thank you for this link, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Unimportant Thank you as well, This helps me learn even more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transistors are a unity gain buffer for the opamp output, the diodes are for biasing the transistors.

The buffer allows the opamp to drive a lower impedance load than it could directly. You should be able to verify this in your simulations by trying to drive low impedance loads with and without the buffer.

The buffer voltage gain will be slightly below unity because of the Vbe of the transistors, but taking the feedback from after the buffer compensates for this. The buffer is meant to provide current and power gain.

Comment: This answer is very helpful and I learned a lot from it, thank you very much. When you say "drive a lower impedance load" does that mean lower impedance for the input, or for the feedback loop, or something else entirely?

Comment: @user199827463 I mean the load, such as a speaker or headphones. With the circuit shown that might be as low as 54 ohms for 8 ohm headphones, the opamp cannot supply enough current to drive that on it's own so a buffer is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes a lot of sense the way you explained it. I never knew that was a thing, thank you for helping me learn more.